# Cron expression for daily start at 09.30 AM with 30 minute interval

Tags: java, cron

I want my schedule job to run daily between specific time and at spefic interval.

For example interval of 30 minute starting from 09.30AM to 11.30PM.

Start time, end time and interval will be configurable
at run time.

I tried with following cron expression :
0 30/30 09-23 1/1 * ?

But this runs at every hour instead of every 30 minutes.

If not possible with cronexpression then appreciate any way of doing it with java.

Note: start time, end time and interval must be configurable at run time

Comment: If that doesn't work you could try 2 entries: one with `0/30` or `0,30` for 10:00 - 23:30 and one explicitly for 9:30.

Comment: @MikhailAntonov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610654/set-cronjob-to-run-every-31-minutes-between-certain-hours does not work for this. 
0 0,30 09-23 1/1 * ? and 0 0,30 09-23 1/1 * ? both will start with 09.00AM instead of 09.30AM

Comment: @Thomas Two expression can work but as mentioned start time, end time and interval can be change by user at run time. So how to decide at run time that specified time and interval will need one expression or two.

Comment: Well, that depends on the options you're providing, e.g. what can be selected as the interval. Note that if you'd allow for things like 7 minute intervals you might even need more than 2 expressions. If you'd take care of that, e.g. only allow for intervals of 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20 and 30 minutes (all are factors of 60), you could probably do simple checks like: if starttime - interval is still in the same hour as the start time you'll need a separate expression (in your case 9:30 - 30 minutes = 9:00, i.e. for both the hour is 9. On the other hand 9:15 - 30 minutes wouldn't be a problem.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already stated in the comments you might need more than one expression. Assuming you restrict the interval to factors of 60 (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20,30,60) you should need 1 to 3 expressions.

Example: if you'd say every 5 minutes starting from 9:45 to 23:15 you'd need the following expressions:

```
0   45/5      9 * * ?   //every 5 minutes from 9:45 to 9:59
0    0/5  10-22 * * ?   //every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 22:59
0 0-15/5     23 * * ?   //every 5 minutes from 23:00 to 23:15
```

You should be able to calculate that from just the data you got. Here's a quick hack to get you started:

```
public static List<String> getExpressions( int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour, int endMinute, int interval) {
  List<String> expressions = new ArrayList<>();

  //If the start minute is greater than the interval we need a separate expression for the first hour
  if( startMinute >= interval ) {     
    expressions.add( String.format( "0 %d/%d %d * * ?", startMinute, interval, startHour ) );

    //the main expression needs to start as early as possible in the second hour, 
    //e.g. if you start at 9:33 and have 5 minute intervals it would need to start at 10:03  (9+1 = 10, 33%5 = 3)
    startMinute %= interval;
    startHour++;
  }

  //If the end minute is lower than the last run in the end hour we need a separate epxression for the last hour
  if( endMinute < (  startMinute + 60 - interval ) ) {     
    expressions.add( String.format( "0 %d-%d/%d %d * * ?", startMinute, endMinute, interval, endHour ) );

    //the main expression needs to run up to the second to last hour
    endHour--;
  }

  //if the main expression would still be 2+ hours in length
  if( startHour < endHour ) {        
    expressions.add( String.format( "0 %d/%d %d-%d * * ?", startMinute, interval, startHour, endHour ) );
  }
  //if the main expression is only 1 hour long don't use x-x
  else if ( startHour == endHour ) {
    expressions.add( String.format( "0 %d/%d %d * * ?", startMinute, interval, startHour ) );
  }

  return expressions;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is quite late but might help someone else eventually. You don't really need multiple expressions to achieve your goal.

`0,30 9-13 * * MON-FRI  // Every 30 mins from 9:00AM to 1:30PM weekdays` 
`30 9-13 * * MON-FRI  // Every 30 mins from 9:30AM to 1:30PM weekdays`